# Aqaurium fish tank leveling

Tags: wood, level, leveling

I have an aquarium I am trying to level on a garage floor. The flooring is concrete slab and aquarium is on a metal stand.

Since garages have a slope to them, my aquarium is off on the left side by 2 inches. The stand is 8ft long. This aquarium is 700 gallons. When will filled with water, sand, etc. we are talking close to 7000lbs total possibly more.

I was wondering if I can put a 2 by 4 with some plywood on the left two corners to help lift it. Would 2 by 4 be able to hold this?

[image]

I have attached a picture. I currently have it shimmed with plastic composite shims but I am too afraid to fill the tank with water yet. On the picture you can also see little piece of metal extruded down which is the corner on which the tank stands. All the corner have pieces extruded out meant to be legs.  I would like to make it more sturdy. Any suggestions on what I can do to support the right side of the tank?

Comment: Can you estimate the bottom surface area of the stand that will sit fully on the 2x4/plywood?  2 inches by 8 feet is much better than a couple of square inches just on the ends.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement. It's about furniture support, essentially.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid wood in this application. If choosing wood, be sure it's pressure treated wood, since concrete contact is bad for promoting rot, and aquarium slop is also bad for promoting rot. Rot would be ...bad.

I level my aquarium with "coaster" quality CDs, (i.e. scrap or junk or obsolete) some of which date back to AOL mailing theirs out. They are relatively large, so pressure is low, and they are quite stable. Polycarbonate (which is the material, as far as I know) has excellent compressive strength at 17,000 PSI or greater. However, given the scale of yours and the environment, I'd suggest a different method.

[image: brick serving to level and elevate a freezer on an uneven floor]

There's an old, uneven, and prone to wetness basement floor in one location. When I need to set something level there, and keep it out of the occasional water on the floor, I mortar in bricks to land the feet on. It's very easy to adjust the bricks to be dead level by gently tapping if too high, or pulling them up and adding more mortar if too low, and then leave them alone until the mortar sets. They won't rot, they are very stable, and they will take literal tons of loading. If the steel foot (which is not that obvious in the picture, or not what I expect from your text description) is excessively small, a bit of steel plate (1/4" thick or so) between the foot and the brick will help to spread the load.

Comment: I would be cautious as the bottom may not be able to support that weight. I would fully support the bottom. You could make a wooden frame, fill it with cement and level it.

Comment: If the stand **has** feet, it's designed to be supported **by the feet.**

Comment: Seems to me a half height brick or three would do the job.  1.5" tall, use a piece of scrap lumber to fill/wedge any gap.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that pine has a compressive strength greater than 2000 PSI so you should be fine assuming the feet are larger than 1/2 square inch and and the weight is distributed across 4 feet

If the 2x4 is some stronger material (like oak or steel) so much the better.